# How to translate c# async Task to Unity coroutine

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task, using

I'm implementing bidirectional streaming RPC using protobuf in Unity.
[C# documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/csharp/) doesn't reflect Unity's C# 4.x Equivalent, so I need to translate it to coroutine-alternative method, I believe. Basiacally it serves as a subscription which outputs server response in period.

```
using (var call = client.RouteChat())
{
var responseReaderTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
    {
        var note = call.ResponseStream.Current;
        Console.WriteLine("Received " + note);
    }
});

foreach (RouteNote request in requests)
{
    await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
}
await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
await responseReaderTask;
}
```